# Using $wpdb in a plugin, what sort of data does it return?

Tags: plugins, wpdb

I have following code:

```
<?php
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

global $wpdb;


$myoption =  get_option( 'fixformdata_options' );
$myoptionValue = maybe_unserialize( $myoption );    

$result2 = $wpdb->get_row
(
    $wpdb->prepare
    (
        "SELECT * FROM {$myoptionValue['tablename']} WHERE personeelsNummer = %d", $q
    )
);

if($result2) {
  echo  json_encode( $result2 );
}

?>
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
var parsed = JSON.parse(response);
```

There seems to be something wrong with the returned data, but I don't know what...

Help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked at the response itself? Without actually looking at the data, you can't know what the issue is.

Comment: Yeah i was just doing this, it seems that get_option doesn't get called... at first it was working properly, I have no clue why it isn't working now

Comment: What context is this code in? Are you sure WordPress is loaded? Do you check the `$myoption` variable first? Do you have debugging/error reporting enabled?

Comment: -How can I be sure that Wordpress is loaded? I don't know what that means, I mean, I can get on my website and everythings loads fine.
-Why do I need to check the $myoption? Also how do I do this?
-Yes

Comment: Where does the code in your question exist? A file of its own? In a plugin? In your theme?

Comment: In a plugin

/wp-content/plugins/getuser.php

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [codex on `wpdb`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). In your case, `get_row` returns the first row of the result set as an object. There's no need for any `mysqli_*` functions when using `$wpdb`.

```
if ( $result2 )
    echo json_encode( $result2 );
```

And a heads up for [SQL injection](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Protect_Queries_Against_SQL_Injection_Attacks) - use the `prepare` method:

```
$wpdb->get_row(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT * FROM {$myoptionValue['tablename']} WHERE personeelsNummer = %s",
        $q
    )
);
```

If `personeelsNummer` is an integer, use the placeholder `%d` instead of `%s`

Comment: I updated my code, it still doesn't work ...